Estimating the size of data when loaded from parquet file into an arrow table
I have a pyarrow table with a large amount of columns (>2000). For 1000 rows, it takes about 20M RAM. For many columns, there’s a single value over all the rows. When I save it to a parquet file, the size of the resulting file on storage is ~4MB.
Now, when looking on the total_compressed_size (=size on storage?) and total_uncompressed_size (=size in RAM?) parameters in the parquet file metadata, I would expect them to reflect this X4 ratio. But the values for both parameters in my case are ~2M, with the ‘total_uncompressed_size’ value only slightly larger than total_compressed_size.
So, my question is whether I misinterpret the meaning of these parameters or they are just not reliable? And, most importantly, is there any reliable way to estimate the size a given parquet file will take in RAM before loading the whole data?

Parquet is a columnar storage format (Could be consider Hybrid if we take on account row-groups), which means it stores data by columns rather than rows. Moreover parquet compress the data in a columnar way and associates to each column the metadata for that column. In your case you will have metadata for 2000 columns where you only have a single value (not very efficient).
How data is store in disk:
The columnar data format means that the data in memory is store in order of columns first save all data of the first column follow by the second and so on. Note a csv does the opposite an store row 1 follow by row 2 and so on. In parquet when you have a lot of rows the data will be store in a columnar way within a row group, a normal size of a row group is 128 MB thus in your case you have a single row group.
Here is the structure of a parquet file with 3 columns and 2 row-groups:

Understanding the Parquet compression:
Parquet does compression mainly in a column, this is mainly under the assumption that data within a column is the same type and many characters will repeat. In general the compression is done using something call dictionary compression and run-length encoding plus bit-packing.
In simple words if you have strings this will be converted to numbers (storing numbers is much more efficient) and create a dictionary of this data. And then you will do the run-length encoding.
Here is an image I have created explaining this for a Column (I think an image is easy to explain this):

I do believe that the parameters total_compressed_size and total_uncompressed_size correspond to the sizes before and after the compression algorithm has been applied, and has nothing to do with the size in memory:

total_compressed_size: integer representing the size of the data in bytes after it has been compressed.

total_uncompressed_size: integer representing the size of the data in bytes before it has been compressed. Gives you an idea of the
original size of the data before any compression algorithms were
applied.


In you case the compression is very low if in many of your columns you have a single value. and a lot of columns which generates lot of meta data this explains the little difference in the compression values you have
what is the metadata used for:
Since we have read and create all this dictionaries for every column, some important information is store in the footer of the file as metadata containing information for all row groups and all the columns. This metadata is used to speed up reading. For example we could read only columns or row-groups that contain certain information. Imagine I have a file with two row groups of the above column where in one group I do not have "Bananas". If I want to read only rows related to Bananas, the parquet reader the first thing it does is reads the metadata and only load row-groups containing Banana.
Data in Memory:
Finally notice that PyArrow tables in memory can have significant overhead compared to their serialized form on disk. This overhead includes pointers, memory alignment, and additional structures used by the Arrow format to facilitate efficient columnar operations and read all metadata. When there are more columns than rows, each column might contain a lot of metadata and pointers relative to the amount of actual data, leading to increased overhead. I am not sure how to make sure of the size in memory of the data once is loaded but I recommend loading only the columns you are going to work with.
