how to effeciently write chunks to partitioned dataset?
I have multiple level of index in my data, for example
schema = pa.schema(
    [
        ('level1', pa.dictionary(pa.int64(), pa.utf8())),
        ('level2', pa.binary(16)),
        ('level3', pa.int64()),
        ('doc', pa.string())
    ]
)

usually I have 10-100 level2 for each level1, 100k to 3M level3 in each level2
I partition the dataset by level1/level2
apparently if I create a table for each level3 chunk all the level1 and level2 values are the same.
Normally we prepare the chunk as table then write to disk.
However, the table actually wasted lots of memory space to store the exact same index values.
I wonder is there a way to make this more memory efficient?

can you give the code you use to save the data? If I understand correctly you could have an average of 55 level 2 partitons (10+100)/2. If we consider you have a 1000 level1 different rows you can end with 55000 small parquet files where the metadata could be the problem behind the size? Maybe order by level1 and 2 and partition only by level1 can reduce the size? Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78646608/estimating-the-size-of-data-when-loaded-from-parquet-file-into-an-arrow-table/78647130#78647130

I think the meatadata is not really the problem, the file is not that small since 3M rows can be very big already if the data size is big enough. And I think the major problem is arrow does not do any tricks on multi-level index, or do any tricks to compress the data in memory representation. The multi-columns as multi-level index approach is essential wrong, we need some tree structure for this to be efficient. Currently I quite the partitioning approach completely, we basically need a db like multi-level index to store the row id, then save only the data in columns.

You have a few options to store chunks in various levels:
A) Store chunks at each level
Each chunk level is stored in its own index, at the expense of space as there will be repeating text (3 levels = 3x replication), but you can easily retrieve a whole doc from a retrieved chunk.
B) Store the lowest level only, with meta
Metadata refers to the other levels, and aggregate chunks on retrieval. That is space savvy but more expensive on retrieval.
C) A mix of the 2
Store chunks at several levels, but not at all levels, depending on what you need. For example if you chunk PDFs into sentences, you might want to retrieve sentences from vector store, but then need to show the whole page in your UI, then you can store the lowest level and the page level only, but not the document level.
D) Offload some content to a separate store
For example you might want to store PDFs page by page in object storage, while storing chunked text into the vector store. Instead of retrieving from your memory store, you pull the doc page from object storage directly from a URL in metadata in the chunk, when you need to retrieve it
